# How to fill a path with a radial gradient in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to fill a path with a radial gradient, but no matter what I try, it always ends up being one solid color (as in the image below). It should transition from red to blue.

How do you fill a path with a radial gradient in SwiftUI? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
         Rectangle()
             .foregroundColor(Color.black)
          Path { path in
             path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200), radius: 100, startAngle: .degrees(0), endAngle: .degrees(360), clockwise: true)
          }
             .fill(RadialGradient(
                 gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red, .blue]),
                 center: UnitPoint(x: 200.0, y: 200),
                 startRadius: 20.0,
                 endRadius: 100.0
             ))
             .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `center: .center`

Comment: @koen That seems to center the gradient **in the middle of the screen**. What I need is for the gradient to be centered **in the center of the circle**.

Comment: Ah yes. Not on a Mac now, so cannot test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, `UnitPoint`'s `x` and `y` are values **between 0 and 1**. Some simple math solved the problem.

[image: demo]

This works:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let x: Double = 200.0
    private let y: Double = 200.0
    private let radius: CGFloat = 100.0
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            Path { path in
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: self.x, y: self.y), radius: self.radius, startAngle: .degrees(0), endAngle: .degrees(360), clockwise: true)
            }
               .fill(RadialGradient(
                   gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red, .blue]),
                   center: UnitPoint(
                    x: CGFloat(self.x / Double(geo.size.width)),
                    y: CGFloat(self.y / Double(geo.size.height))
                   ),
                   startRadius: self.radius * 0.30,
                   endRadius: self.radius
               ))
            
        }
    }
}
```